# IIB ESQL timezone UTC to CET

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I am trying to add the timezone difference to a TIMESTAMP, I tried the following but this is not adequate since the difference fluctuates with the summer and winter hour (respectively plus 2 or plus 1).

```
SET dateTimeCET = dateTimeUTC + CAST(2 AS INTERVAL HOUR);
```

I searched IBM documentation and the web.
I am looking for the correct code to add the conversion from UTC to CET in ESQL.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, hope it can help someone.

```
SET dateTimeCET = dateTimeUTC + LOCAL_TIMEZONE;
```

More info in documentation.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=functions-local-timezone-function